# x87 double addition don't work

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att, x87

I defined an assembly function which takes three parameters (int, double, double) which should add two putted double value and return the result of this addition. And I don't know why the below code doesn't work:

```
extern double ftaylor(unsigned int n, double x, double y);
int main()
{
    double z  = 14;
    z = ftaylor(30, 13.45, 7);


    printf("%f", z);
    return 0;
}
```

And the assembly function:

```
.globl ftaylor

ftaylor:
    .lcomm state, 8
    .lcomm state2, 8
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    push %rax

    mov %rdi, %rax
    movsd %xmm0, state
    movsd %xmm1, state2

    finit

    fld state
    fld state2

    fadd %st(1), %st(0)

    fstp state
    fstp state2

    movsd state, %xmm0

    pop %rax
    mov %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

The result printed on the terminal is `13.45`. It looks like the processor doesn't perform the addition. I don't know why.

Comment: What is the argument `unsigned int n` for? And what do you expect the sum of the two double values `13.45` + `0` to be if it is not `13.45`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't move the arguments from `%xmm`-registers to the FPU via the stack? Using a static variable seems odd.

Comment: What is this blasphemous mix of SSE and x87?? And, as written, you simply overwrite `state`.

Comment: In the future this function should compute the specific taylor function, and the unsigned int is one of nedeed parameter. But now i only try to run the any floating point functionality.

Comment: The mix of SSE and x87 must be done, because in c the double and float parameter are passed to the function by xmm0 registers, and i wan't to use this function in c.

Comment: Never mind the overwrite part - AT&T syntax tricked me! Still, why don't you calculate everything using SSE? And, as noted, your output is correct given the inputs.

Comment: @Weather Vane for the 13.45 and 7 it don't work too.

Comment: Why not `addsd %xmm1, %xmm0`? No need to use x87 to add floating-point numbers.

Comment: Yes, but i must use x87.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that `fld/fstp` without a suffix defaults to `s(hort)` which is otherwise known as single precision float. But you have double precision values, so you should use `fldl/fstpl`. As others pointed out, do not use x87 unless absolutely necessary. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

`state`, as calculated by the x87 code fragment, gets overwritten by value stored in xmm0:

```
...
movsd %xmm0, state
...
... x87 calculation of state ...
...
movsd state, %xmm0
...
```

After some back-and-forth, it does seem like the AT&T syntax *may* use the reversed arguments order, that is, `mov a, b` moves *from* b *to* a, which would explain the overwriting of the input argument, and the output observed by the OP. What exactly syntax his assembler is using remains unclear though, so I am a bit tentative about this answer.

Other possible reasons have been pointed out in other answers and comments.

Comment: Err, no. The result of the x87-computation is saved into `state`, but whatever ABI the OP is using probably demands floating-point `return` to be in a `%xmm`-register, so that is what `movsd state, %xmm0` is doing.

Comment: You mean, this assembly notation uses `mov from, to`, not `mov to, from`?